# cover a div until page reload

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to cover a search facets list with a div to prevent clicking on other facets until the page has reloaded with the filtered results. I'm very new to this, but here's what I have so far:

(.info-inner-cover is set to display: none;)

```
ns.toggleSearchCover = function () {
    $('.sf-facet').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.info-inner-cover').toggle();
    });
};
```

After clicking on the .sf-facet, the page reloads, and then I want my .info-inner-cover to go away. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Try $('.info-inner-cover').show();

Comment: I am probably adding too much markup, but I'm getting closer here:     ns.toggleSearchCover = function () {
        $('.sf-facet').click(function(){ 
            $('.info-inner-cover').addClass("covered");
        });
    };
    
    ns.toggleSearchUncover = function () {
            $('.info-inner-cover').addClass("uncovered");
    }; I just realized that the page will be making an ajax call, so I need to change the state based on the completion of the call.